# Magento 2 - get key

Tags: magento2, url, router

when I click on orders and then on shipments, this URL is generated:

> mysite.com/admin/sales/order/index/key/b1b504c4b09c982d420f001572349abbde9837cbc363e03c669099baa537af0e/

How can I get the key for an order or shipment?

> /key/b1b504c4b09c982d420f001572349abbde9837cbc363e03c669099baa537af0e/

Thanks!

Comment: What actually you want to do?

Comment: I put a button to the order overview and if it's being pressed I want it to print the package slip.

Comment: @LKlmn please check updated answer. You can ask me if any query.

Comment: why your want this key? Please tell us. t

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simple use the method `$this->getUrl()` in a block that extends `Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Button\Generic`, the secret key will be added automatically.

Sample code for a custom button class:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Catalog\Product\Edit\Button;

use Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Button\Generic;

class MyButton extends Generic
{
    public function getButtonData()
    {


        return [
            'label' => __('Do something'),
            'on_click' => "window.location.href={$this->getUrl('my/module/url')}",
            'sort_order' => 999
        ];
    }
}
```

Maybe there's a similar class for sales order buttons.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. can you give me a sample for "my/module/url"?

Comment: it depends. if you want to call a URL and do anything, you need to implement a Controller; more info about this can be found on Google or here: https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/how-to-create-controllers-magento-2.html if you have problems with this, I think you should search MagentoSE or open another question

Answer (score 2):

```
$object = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$url = $object->get(\Magento\Backend\Model\UrlInterface::class);
echo $url->getSecretKey();
```

Answer (score 1):

For get key value :

```
echo $this->getRequest()->getParam('key');
```

**Note : Do not use ObjectManager Direct. It defeats the purpose of dependency injection.**